# is coordinate mapping same as pixel mapping in matlab for delaunay triangulation

Tags: image, matlab, transform, delaunay, matlab-cvst

I have to transform pixels from one image onto another image, by feature detection. I have calculated the projective transformation matrix. One image is the base image, and the other is a linearly translated image.

Now I have to define a larger grid and assign pixels from the base image to it. For example, if the base image is 20 at `(1,1)`, on the larger grid I will have 20 at `(1,1)`. and assign zeroes to all the unfilled values of the grid. Then I have to map the linearly translated image onto the base image and write my own algorithm based on "delaunay triangulation" to interpolate between the images.

My question is that when I map the translated image to the base image, I use the concept

```
(w,z)=inv(T).*(x,y)  
A=inv(T).*B
```

where `(w,z)` are coordinates of the base image, `(x,y)` are coordinates of the translated image, `A` is a matrix containing coordinates `(w z 1)` and `B` is matrix containing coordinates `(x y 1)`.

If I use the following code I get the new coordinates, but how do I relate these things to the image? Are my pixels from the second image also translated onto the first image? If not, how can I do this?

```
close all; clc; clear all;

image1_gray=imread('C:\Users\Javeria Farooq\Desktop\project images\a.pgm');
figure; imshow(image1_gray); axis on; grid on;
title('Base image');
impixelinfo
hold on

image2_gray =imread('C:\Users\Javeria Farooq\Desktop\project images\j.pgm');
figure(2); imshow(image2_gray); axis on; grid on;
title('Unregistered  image1');
impixelinfo

% Detect and extract features from both images
points_image1= detectSURFFeatures(image1_gray, 'NumScaleLevels', 100, 'NumOctaves', 5,  'MetricThreshold', 500 );
points_image2 = detectSURFFeatures(image2_gray, 'NumScaleLevels', 100, 'NumOctaves', 12,  'MetricThreshold', 500 );

[features_image1, validPoints_image1] = extractFeatures(image1_gray, points_image1);
[features_image2, validPoints_image2] = extractFeatures(image2_gray, points_image2);

% Match feature vectors
indexPairs = matchFeatures(features_image1, features_image2, 'Prenormalized', true) ;

% Get matching points
matched_pts1 = validPoints_image1(indexPairs(:, 1));
matched_pts2 = validPoints_image2(indexPairs(:, 2));

figure; showMatchedFeatures(image1_gray,image2_gray,matched_pts1,matched_pts2,'montage');
legend('matched points 1','matched points 2'); 
figure(5); showMatchedFeatures(image1_gray,image3_gray,matched_pts4,matched_pts3,'montage');
legend('matched points 1','matched points 3'); 

% Compute the transformation matrix using RANSAC
[tform, inlierFramePoints, inlierPanoPoints, status] = estimateGeometricTransform(matched_pts1, matched_pts2, 'projective')
figure(6); showMatchedFeatures(image1_gray,image2_gray,inlierPanoPoints,inlierFramePoints,'montage');
[m n] = size(image1_gray);
image1_gray = double(image1_gray);
[x1g,x2g]=meshgrid(m,n) % A MESH GRID OF 2X2
k=imread('C:\Users\Javeria Farooq\Desktop\project images\a.pgm');
ind = sub2ind( size(k),x1g,x2g);

%[tform1, inlierFramepPoints, inlierPanopPoints, status] = estimateGeometricTransform(matched_pts4, matched_pts3, 'projective')
%figure(7); showMatchedFeatures(image1_gray,image3_gray,inlierPanopPoints,inlierFramepPoints,'montage');
%invtform=invert(tform)
%x=invtform
%[xq,yq]=meshgrid(1:0.5:200.5,1:0.5:200.5);

r=[];
A=[];
k=1;

%i didnot know how to refer to variable tform so i wrote the transformation
%matrix from variable structure tform
T=[0.99814272,-0.0024304502,-1.2932052e-05;2.8876773e-05,0.99930143,1.6285858e-06;0.029063907,67.809265,1]

%lets take i=1:400 so my r=2 and resulting grid is 400x400
for i=1:200
    for j=1:200
        A=[A; i j 1];
        z=A*T;
        r=[r;z(k,1)/z(k,3),z(k,2)/z(k,3)];
        k=k+1;
    end
end

%i have transformed the coordinates but how to assign values??
%r(i,j)=c(i,j)
d1=[];
d2=[];
for l=1:40000
    d1=[d1;A(l,1)];
    d2=[d2;r(l,1)];
    X=[d1 d2];
    X=X(:);
end

c1=[];
c2=[];
for l=1:40000
    c1=[c1;A(l,2)];
    c2=[c2;r(l,2)];
    Y=[c1 c2];
    Y=Y(:);
end

%this delaunay triangulation is of vertices as far as i understand it
%doesnot have any pixel value of any image
DT=delaunayTriangulation(X,Y);
triplot(DT,X,Y);
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the code

Comment: You can add a codeblock by editing your answer and indenting each line of code by four spaces, or by highlighting all of your code and pressing Ctrl+k

Comment: thanku i did that .can anyone please help me out

Comment: I updated your question and code for readability, since the easier it is to understand, the more likely you are to get responses.  Please review my edits to make sure that they still accurately convey your question.

Comment: @nispio thank you sir it conveys my question, i m looking for an answer now

Comment: After reading your question, I'm still not sure that it is clear what you are asking.  If pixel `(1,1)` in the first image maps to pixel `(1,1)` in the second image, then this hardly qualifies as a translation/transformation.

Comment: sir from first image i copy the pixel values as they are to lager grid. my problem is that when i apply transformation to a second image and bring it to the larger grid my (1,1) of second image comes to (1.6,67.3) of larger grid. the coordinates are mapped correctly. i cannot use roundoff command because i have to use the floating point coordinates to construct delaunay triangulation. my question is how to assign the pxel values from second image to the floating point coordinates on larger grid

Comment: I'm very sorry, but I still can't understand what it is you are doing.  Unless you can find a more clear explanation of your problem (perhaps using pictures) I can't help you. Maybe you could change your title to include "Delaunay Triangulation," and somebody who is more familiar with it might be able to understand your problem.  Good luck.

Comment: ok sir i am going to edit it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by using these two steps:

1. Use transformPointsForward command to transform the coordinates of image ,using the tform object returned by estimateGeometrcTransform
2. Use the scatteredInterpolant class in Matlab and use command scatteredInterpolant 
   to assign the transformed coordinates their respective pixel values.

F=scatteredInterpolant(P,z)

here P=nx2 matrix containing all the transformed coordinates

```
z=nx1 matrix containing pixel values of image that is transformed,it is obtained by converting image to column vector using image=image(:)
```

finally all the transformed coordinates are present along with their pixel values on the base image and can be interpolated.

Answer (score 0):

You are doing way too much work here, and I don't think you need the Delaunay Triangulation at all.  Use the `imwarp` function from the Image Processing Toolbox to transform the image. It takes the original image and the `tform` object returned by `estimateGeometricTransform`.

Comment: imwarp function cannot be used because it will linearly interpolate  the transformed pixel values on the grid , however i want to use delaunay triangulation and do interpolation by surface approximation

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is the problem that you are trying to solve? I really can't think of a case of a projective transformation, where a bi-linear or a bi-cubic interpolation is not sufficient. Here's an stereo rectification example, where `imwarp` does just fine: http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/examples/stereo-image-rectification.html

Comment: actually i have to do super resolution of images after projective transformation.i dont have to do  just interpolation so i dont require the kind of interpolation imwarp does else you are right in what you are saying.